# Struts2 disable <s:textfield> using some expression

Tags: jsp, struts2, expression

I have two roles in my app, ROLE_ADMIN & ROLE_USER
Also I have a form with some fields. I would like to have the following:
When user has ADMIN role he is able to edit specific group of fields, when user has USER role he is not able to edit these fields. I don't want to have two different forms, or two copies of fields for every role.

I tried to do something like that:

<s:textfield key="..." **disabled="${myFlag}"** >, where myFlag evaluated from roles.

But I have warning "disabled" does not support runtime expressions.

Is there any way to do this? Or maybe there's better way, for example, by replacing generated input to label ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use the **OGNL expression** by `%{expression}` syntax in a **Struts2 tag**.

```
<s:textfield disabled="%{myFlag}" />
```

---

> how can I set such variable on page?

Doesn't work with `%{myFlag}`? Or you could set the the variable by

```
<s:set var="flag">${myFlag}</s:set>
```

Implementation :

```
<s:textfield disabled="#flag" />
```

Comment: how can I set such variable on page? I tried c:set or s:set, not working with OGNL

Answer (score 0):

Add `cssClass` attribute to those fields and write a javascript function which should e called on body `onload` event

```
function calledonbodyload() {
 <s:if test="%{role=='ROLE_USER'}">
   document.getElementsByClass("yourClass").disabled=true;
 </s:if>
}
```

I am not sure about `getElementByClass()` in plain javascript but jQuery's `$(".yourClass").attr('disabled',true);` worlks perfectly